# HttpClient is extremely very slow - Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I'm trying to download some json from a url. 
I'm debugging the app through my Samsung device, but for some reason, httpclient takes very long to download the data.

When I set the timeout using TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), httpclient takes very long which is not practicable. When I remove the timeout, however, I get TaskCancelled exception which the try catch block catches.

Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Tried checking the permissions: The only permission the app needs is the internet which by default is granted in the debug mode.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

**Edit**

This is the class responsible for downloading the data:

```
 public static class DataSource
    {
        public async static void LoadFrom()
        {
               var uri = new Uri("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?convert=usd&sort=price");    
            try
            {
                bool isConnected = CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected;
                HttpClient myClient = new HttpClient(new Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler());
                var response = await myClient.GetAsync(uri);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var Data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var CoinMarketCapObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CoinMarketCap.CoinMarketCapCurrencyData>(Data);
                    List<Currency> currencies = new List<Currency>();
                    if (CoinMarketCapObject != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var Datum in CoinMarketCapObject.Data)
                        {
                            currencies.Add(new Currency(Datum.Value.name, Datum.Value.symbol, Datum.Value.quotes.USD.price));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (TimeoutException ex)
            {
                // Check ex.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested here.
                // If false, it's pretty safe to assume it was a timeout.
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
            {
                // Check ex.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested here.
                // If false, it's pretty safe to assume it was a timeout.
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Print(e.Message);

            }
        }

    }
```

I'm calling the LoadFrom method from the OnStart Method.

```
protected override void OnStart ()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
            API.DataSource.LoadFrom();
        }
```

Comment: How and where is that method being calling?

Comment: Does data actually return? Are you sure you are not in a deadlock?

Comment: @Nkosi I have added some info...

Comment: If I set the timeout to 30 mins, data will return but it takes forever, otherwise, I get TaskCancelled exception.

Comment: Can you post the code how `myClient` is defined and initialized?

Comment: Does `myClient` (`HttpClient`) is defied to use proxy which is slowing the request?

Comment: If you download the data using a web browser, how long does it take to download?

Comment: I tried the url you provided with a browser. Everything looks fine. Can you post the myclient code ?

Comment: @AnisTissaoui myclient is an HttpClient class.

Comment: @mjwills, in chrome it takes 1 seconds or so.

Comment: Thw answer probably is in how you call this Load() method, Post the whole chain, from the top method (eventhandler) on down.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Alright, I did an edit outlining the class and where I'm calling the method.

Comment: I now see 2 incompatible versions. Make up your mind and post the correct version. Make sure it demonstrates the problem.  An `async void` is always tricky, I can see why you want it here but first, try a non-async version to eliminate all network issues.

Comment: Is there another way to download a string from a uri other than httpclient?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: So I tried this plugin (https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin) and I'm getting true in terms connectivity I even tried to download Microsoft Http libraries to use WebClient but nothing is working...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are using the `HttpClientHandler`. The current recommendation from Xamarin is to use the `AndroidNativeHandler`. This uses the native Android networking stack and has encryption support instead of being virtualised within the .NET runtime. However, the trade-offs are support is only from Android 5 onwards, and some HttpClient features/options are not available.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/http-stack

Comment: I changed that as recommended in the link but nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Huawei P9 Lite ==> few seconds to get the result...

```
public async void LoadFrom()
{
    var uri = new Uri("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?convert=usd&sort=price");
    try
    {
        HttpClient myClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = await myClient.GetStringAsync(uri);
        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex)
    {
        // Check ex.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested here.
        // If false, it's pretty safe to assume it was a timeout.
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
    {
        // Check ex.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested here.
        // If false, it's pretty safe to assume it was a timeout.
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

Perhaps your myclient has some issues.. or maybe a network problem

Comment: Do you have any permissions set in the project properties?

Comment: What networking settings do you have on in the developer options in your device?